# The Deezer's API page doesn't let me create a new app

Tags: deezer

I'm trying to create a new app on Deezer in this [link](https://developers.deezer.com/myapps/create) but it doesn't let me, i put all the fields in the correct way and accept the policies, then i press "Create" but nothing happens, not even a error message, justo load a couple of seconds and nothing more. The Javascript console show me an error, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: myapps is not defined" at line 199 on "create".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fill full url with HTTP scheme (eg. **http://** www.example.com) in these 3 fields:

- Domain
- Redirect URL after authentification
- Link to your Terms of Use